# Versioning on Parquet files from AWS Glue for external table querying with Redshift Spectrum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am working on an ETL pipeline to transform JSON files into Parquet format (storage cost) using AWS Glue batch job, and then query the S3 bucket with Parquet files using RedShift External tables.

My roadblock is how to handle multiple versioning of the Parquet files, so that the external table queries the latest version of the Parquet file or force AWS Glue to overwrite Parquet files and always maintain latest version.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Day | JSON (S3)   | JSON Ver  |Parquet (S3)                         | External Table Query Data          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1   | temp.json   |   1.0     |part-00000-9n83b353-c000.snappy.parquet|  Count 1, includes Parquet i.e. 1.0          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2   | temp.json   |   2.0     |part-00000-7s34s653-c000.snappy.parquet|  Count 2, includes both version, Parquet 1.0 & 2.0|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As a service, S3-AWSGlue-Redshift Spectrum meets my implementation scenario but would like to have a recommendation on how to handle versioning issue.